# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int' | very interesting case?

Tags: python

```
x_=[range(1,1000000)]
def pr(x_):
        for a in x_:
                # is type(a) int ?? 
                if a==2 or  a==3 :
                        x_[a-1]=0
                        continue
                for j in  range(2,a):
                        if(a%j==0):
                                x_[a-1]=0
                                break
pr(x_)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int' | very interesting case?

Answer (score 0):

```
x_=[range(1,1000000)]
```

This will cause `x_` to be `[[1, 2, 3, ... 999999]]`. Note the two brackets. It is a doubly nested list, so `a` will be a list and not an int. If you just want `a` to be an int and `x_` to be `[1, 2, 3, ... 999999]`, try

```
x_ = range(1,1000000)
```

Comment: is output of range( ) function a list ?

Comment: Depends on what version of Python you're using. In 2.7, it's a list. In 3.X, it's a `range` object, which behaves very much like a list, except you can't assign to it. In the interest of version compatibility, you might do `x_ = list(range(1, 10000000))`.